# How to set the name of downloaded file on an HttpResponse?

Tags: node.js, http-headers

I have a simple file-server written with nodejs which responds to requests like a GET request to the servers url like so `www.site.com/cdn/filename/latest` This should let the user make a wget request and get the "latest" version of the file named "filename". The issue is that the resulting file is named "latest" and not "filename".

Is there a way to set the name of the file being sent back in the response via the headers?

The method below writes the response.

```
function sendFile(res, filepath) {
   res.writeHead(200, {
       'Content-Type': mime.lookup(filepath)
   })
   fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Content disposition is the header to use. [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html)

```
const path = require('path')
function sendFile(res, filepath) {
   var filename = path.basename(filepath)
   res.writeHead(200, {
       'Content-Type': mime.lookup(filepath),
       'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="'+filename+'"'
   })
   fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(res)
}
```